# jQuery val() not working with Caret logic in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, caret

I'm working with an input field which I've mapped keyCodes for so that a keyboard input will render a different language character into the input field.

The problem becomes when the characters reach the end of the input 'view' any additional input for "mapped" characters which are using the jQuery val() method will not be interpreted as a key input from the browser hence keeping the last inputted character always visible.

So I have to add caret logic (bottom input in jsfiddle uses the caret logic) but this doesn't work on Chrome/(webkit?)

Here is a jsfiddle of my example.  http://jsfiddle.net/dwickwire/S9EKN/

EDIT: I tested with the following versions, works in FF but not in Chrome for me

Mac Snow Leapord OSX 10.6.7

Chrome: v 11.0.696.68, v 11.0.696.71 - don't work

Firefox: 4.0.1 - works

Windows Chrome: -v unsure  - doesn't work

I'm unsure of how I can resolve this, any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: It works in Chrome for me... v 11.0.696.68

Comment: @Fosco Are you certain that you tested this correctly?  Its a lot of jargon I have here in order to test properly :P  I've tested it on Windows and Mac with Chrome on numerous computers and verified my example is not working.

Comment: @Pointy Safari does not work either -v 5.0.5

Comment: It does not work for me on Linux in either Firefox *or* Chrome.

Comment: I works in Chrome 11 on windows

Comment: @Neal it does not work in Chrome 10 on Windows for me; I'm updating now. Understand that it's not just the character replacement - it's the "scrolling" of the text in the input field that's not working.

Comment: ... and it does not work in Chrome 11 on Windows (XP) either.

Comment: It doesn't work on Chrome 11.0.696.71 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save and add to the `scrollLeft` position of the input, it will update and keep the typed character in view. Although, it fails if you click and start typing in the middle of the input.

I updated the second input [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/S9EKN/19/) with the code below. Also note that the input and test span that is added should have the same font size.

```
input_2.bind('keydown.keyboard', function(e) {
    var key = "",
        current_val = input_2.val(),
        pos = input_2.caret(),
        start_pos = pos.start,
        end_pos = pos.end,
        scroll = $(this).scrollLeft();

    // some mapped keys
    switch (e.which) {
        // e key
    case 69:
        key = "ε";
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
        // f key            
    case 70:
        key = "φ";
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
        // z key                
    case 90:
        key = "ζ";
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
        // a key
    case 65:
        key = "α";
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
    }

    if (key !== '') {
        var test = $('<span class="test">&nbsp;' + key + '</span>').appendTo('body');
        scroll += test.width();
        test.remove();
    }

    input_2.val(current_val + key);
    //Insert/Replace text at caret then restore caret        
    input_2.value = current_val.substr(0, start_pos) + key + current_val.substr(end_pos, current_val.length);
    input_2.caret(start_pos + key.length, start_pos + key.length);
    if (key !== '') {
        $(this).scrollLeft(scroll);
    }

});
```

---

Update: the scrollLeft position seemed to be a bit off, so if you add a `&nbsp;` inside the span with the character, it works out much better ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S9EKN/21/))

Comment: Although it does work it feels a little unpredictable, (ie. stylings and DOM structures will always be different), I'm hoping for a solution where I don't have to add dom nodes and calculate font width because the dynamics might change from site to site.

Comment: Ok. So using your scrollLeft idea I managed to get it a bit more dynamic by calculating the width off of the fontSize in the input. Here's the working link… jsfiddle.net/dwickwire/S9EKN/25 Thank you so much! Tested Chrome -v 11.0.696.71 FF 4.0.1, Safari 5.0.5, IE6, IE9, IE9 comp mode for IE7 all work.